# Label name for ModelAdmin in Django

Tags: python, django

how can I give this class a label which is shown in the backend instead of "EditedAddress"?

```
class EditedAddressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('comp_name','fam_name', 'fon')
    search_fields = ['fam_name','comp_name']


admin.site.register(EditedAddress,EditedAddressAdmin)
```

Comment: What is the verbose_name of EditedAddress?

Comment: i just want to change the label which is displayed in the backend...

Comment: I understand that, but have you set a verbose_name on EditedAddress already?

Comment: no!!!! Ist that the way to go?

Comment: See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can adjust the way your model name is displayed by adding a verbose_name and/or verbose_name_plural to your model:

```
class EditedAddress(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Edited Address'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Edited Addresses'
```

Comment: yeah, but if you need 2 admins with different names for one model? Way to control django admin is a must

Comment: Use a [Proxy Model](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/add_model_twice.html) in that case and change the name of the proxy.